# Highest DC current gain

Tags: current, bias, common-emitter, emitter

I drew a circuit with a transistor (ktc3198) at heart for getting the highest DC gain the transistor can offer. I used [its input and output characteristics](https://alltransistors.com/adv/pdfdatasheet_secos/ktc3198.pdf).

And based on that I made a little circuit. But I can't seem to choose suitable q point to achieve the highest current gain.

[image]

Comment: Have you chosen (or calculated) any component values?  According to your linked datasheet the specified max hfe is based on an operating point of: Ic = 2ma and Vce = 6V.

Comment: Did you really mean CURRENT gain? || As others note, that's a device parameter which can be optimised from looking at the data sheet. || VOLTAGE gain of a single CE stage with Re bypased is 38.4 x voltage across collector resistor. (Really) . (Re not bypassed gives lower gain.

Comment: I thought common emmitter configuration for current gain is purely resistive...

Comment: @imranmuhd  I do not understand the comment about purely resistive.  Current gain is a feature of the device (KTC3198 here)

Comment: When you mentioned bypassing Re , i thought you were referring to including a capacitor

Comment: Imran muhd, may I ask you WHY you want to realize such a circuit with the highest possible current gain?

Comment: The datasheet states a 500mw of power. So i wasn't sure: is it the total power at the collector or the overall power the transistor can dissipate.

Answer (score 1):

The datasheet for the KTC3198 transistor you found has the current gain in three groups at a collector current of 2mA: O= 70-140, Y= 120-240 and G= 200-400.

Digikey sell them with a 4th group (BL) that has a high current gain of 300-700.
The current gain at a collector current of 150mA is much lower.
The graphs show "typical" ones that you might find.
[image: KTC3198]